# Jquery Droppable clone, but do not remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery's drag and drop photo manager, and require some slightly altered functionality.
You can view the eg. in the link below.

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

What I want to be able to do, is when you drag an image into the drop-zone, instead of fading from the original list, I want to add a class to it.

I can't quite figure out where I need to do this?

Comment: should image stay in the list or should it be removed ??

Comment: it should stay in list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$trash.droppable({
  accept: "#gallery > li",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.draggable.addClass('my-new-thing');
        var $list = $( "ul", $trash ).length ? $( "ul", $trash ) : $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $trash );
        ui.draggable.clone().append( recycle_icon ).appendTo( $list ).fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: This add's a class. But when I do this, the drop function no longer works.

Comment: If that means the drop function is working, I guess it would be the recieve drop function that is not, because it will no longer accept the content

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this

```
    // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
    $trash.droppable({
        accept: "#gallery > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            deleteImage( ui.draggable );
            ui.draggable.addClass('new1');
        }
    })
```

Comment: This works for adding a class, but it does not prevent the original item from moving/fading out.

In the jquery example. When you drag the element into the trash it dissapears / fades out instantly. I do not want mine to dissapear.

Comment: @Mark  so i think you want something like this .. when an image will dropped to trash zone image background should be change and it should at both place in original zone as well as trash zone .. is it ??

Comment: I've edited my answer, the important part is to call .clone() on the draggable item, so the original doesn't get removed.

Comment: Thank you! @andygoestohollywood amd Dhaval for all of your help! Andy, your edited answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When your element is in drop-zone, you can catch the event with the `drop` event.

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // Add your class here
    }
});
```

More information on http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop